# MySQL DISTINCT function not working

Tags: mysql, unique, distinct

Using MySQL. The following SQL statement works perfectly:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.DISPNAME, a.UNIT_TYPE, a.MODELNUM, a.DESCRIP, a.DATE_ADDED, b.TYP, c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME FROM jobs_engineering a INNER JOIN unit_types b ON a.UNIT_TYPE=b.ID INNER JOIN users c ON a.AEID=c.USERID ORDER BY a.DATE_ADDED DESC
```

But now I want only unique records to the column `DISPNAME` as that column has multiple repeated values. I add the `DISTINCT` method

```
SELECT a.ID, DISTINCT(a.DISPNAME), a.UNIT_TYPE, a.MODELNUM, a.DESCRIP, a.DATE_ADDED, b.TYP, c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME FROM jobs_engineering a INNER JOIN unit_types b ON a.UNIT_TYPE=b.ID INNER JOIN users c ON a.AEID=c.USERID ORDER BY a.DATE_ADDED DESC
```

But that does not work. MySQL tells me my error is near "DISTINCT"

I've tried:

```
 a.DISTINCT(DISPNAME)
 DISTINCT(DISPNAME)
```

None of those work

Where is my error? Can anyone help?

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list and it must immediately follow the `select` keyword

Comment: Ok. I apologize for the verbage..I will correct the title. Do you have any insight to the issue?

Comment: I wasn't referring to your title. I was referring to the way you use it. It is not a function. `distinct (col1), col2` does not make sense - or at least it is identical to `distinct col1, col2`

Comment: I tried putting DISTINCT as the beginning. It performed a query, but it still gave me all of my values.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(a.DISPNAME), a.ID, .....`

Comment: Again: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It has no "parameters" that are passed. the `(` are useless.

Comment: Function or not it allows `(`

Comment: The problem here is that mysql will accept () implying (as with all my years of PHP / MYSQL experience lol) that this is the way to do it and it applies to a column. It appears I am wrong!

Answer (score 20):

`DISTINCT` is not a function, but a query decorator. This means, you use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT` if you want the query to supress all duplicates.

Now the important part is, a row is a duplicate of another row, if (and **only** if) all columns have the same value.

What you want to achieve is typically solved either

- with a `GROUP BY` on the relevant column and fitting aggregate functions
- with a subquery that has a `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I placed `GROUP BY a.DISPNAME` right before the `ORDER BY` and I got what I needed